# Calling native iOS method with two parametres from UIwebView using JSContext

Tags: objective-c

I want to call iOS native method using JSContext with two parameters.

`-(void)log:(NSString*)msg;` in JSExport works fine when called with viewcontroller.log(logmasg); where viewcontroller is set as JS["viewcontroller"] = objCobj;

with same settings how can I call methos with two parameters

```
-(void)iosMethod:(NSString*)param1 andParam:(NSString*)param2 I tried calling as viewcontroller.iosMethodandParam('I am 1','I am 2');
```

But it do not call that method. 
any help is appreciated .

Comment: Finally I got it working .making viewcontroller.iosMethodandParam('I am 1','I am 2'); to viewcontroller.iosMethodAndParam('I am 1','I am 2'); is solution to this. How it works dont know.If anyone have some clue you can share here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSExportAs macro to a selector that take one or more arguments.

```
@protocol MyClassJavaScriptMethods <JSExport>

JSExportAs(iosMethodWithParam,
           -(void)iosMethod:(NSString*)param1 andParam:(NSString*)param2
           );

@end
```

In Javascript, you can use-

```
MyClassObject.iosMethodWithParam(param1, param2)
```